# Selecting multiple children with same parent in CSS

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm using PHPQuery, which is a PHP port of jQuery, so it also uses CSS selectors. However, one difference is that PHPQuery does not return matched elements in the document order when there are multiple selectors.

Is it possible to combine this into one selector?

```
#article>p,#article>blockquote
```

The only other solution I can think of is:

```
#article>*:not(div):not(table):not(ul):not(...
```

Comment: Pretty sure you answered your own question.. although you could remove `*` .. use: `#article>:not(div):not(table):not(ul)`

Comment: Does the library support `.filter()` method? if yes, you can select all the children and then filter the result.

Comment: .has() ? http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: @undefined According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Traversing), yes it does

Comment: @Izkata Yes, I just checked it, it supports the `.filter()` method, unfortunately as I live in Hell(_Iran_) Google doesn't allow me to have access to it's resources. "_403. That’s an error. Request not allowed from your country That’s all we know._"

Comment: What's the difference between `filter()` and `:not()`?

Comment: `.filter()` is a method and `:not` is a selector, say you have a collection, `.filter()` accepts a callback function and it iterates through the collection, if the returned value of the callback function is truthy it keeps the element otherwise it removes the element from the collection.

Comment: @undefined I believe the [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) has the capabilities of masking where you live and overcoming such country-specific-viewing limits. Maybe I'm misreading it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `phpQuery`(*till 5 minutes ago*) but as it works like jQuery, using it's `.filter()` method should do the trick, the idea is selecting all the children and then filtering the elements that match the criteria.

```
$doc['#article']->children()->filter(function($i, $element) {
    return in_array($element->tagName, array('blockquote', 'p'));
})->foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the selector use [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$('#article>p').add('#article>blockquote')
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the method. The argument to .add()
>   can be pretty much anything that $() accepts, including a jQuery
>   selector expression, references to DOM elements, or an HTML snippet, [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/add/).